# Action script 3 image loading

Tags: actionscript-3

i am trying to load a 1*1 image from a server by using URLLoader, sometimes it loaded and sometimes it give me the error like 408 (Request Time-out).

And same thing when i am trying with javascript then image is always loaded.
So please guide me, which variable of AS3 should i use so that image is always loaded.

Comment: Providing us with a little bit of code would probably help.

Comment: @strah Most likely the code is just a `URLLoader.load()` request. And, Rajesh, can you try loading a 32x32 image instead, for example, to narrow your problem?

Comment: @Vesper Yeah, most likely...

Comment: Rajesh, you should also try loading the image, repeatedly, in your browser. Refresh using CTRL+F5, if you are on Windows, to prevent the cached image from loading. You need to figure out if it is your code or the server that is causing this issue.

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable time spend on it.  Here is the code i am using var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); ldr.load(here is the url); and these lines are in the function and i am using setInterval to call this function every second.